# Unable to apply styles for drop down list in css

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to design multi select drop-down list using css class. I am trying to develop multi select drop-down list box exactly below.

[image]

I have below html code.

```css
.checkbox {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .dropdown-menu {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1000;
            float: left;
            min-width: 150px;
            max-height: 600px;
            overflow-x: visible;
            overflow-y: visible;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 500;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            border-radius: 0;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
            box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
            -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
            background-clip: padding-box;
            color: #464646;
        }

        .btn-group, .btn-group-vertical {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
toggle.btn-default {
    background: #dedede;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    border: 1px solid #2E92FA;
    color: #464646;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group open">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Filter by<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width:100%;">
            <li>
                <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="option1">
                    <label style="margin-left:-30px; margin-right:30px;" class="checkbox-inline" for="inlineCheckbox17">Sensors</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="option1">
                    <label style="margin-left:-30px; margin-right:30px;" class="checkbox-inline" for="inlineCheckbox17">Actuators</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="option1">
                    <label style="margin-left:-30px; margin-right:30px;" class="checkbox-inline" for="inlineCheckbox17">Digital inputs</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="option1">
                    <label style="margin-left:-30px; margin-right:30px;" class="checkbox-inline" for="inlineCheckbox17">Outputs</label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="option1">
                    <label style="margin-left:-30px; margin-right:30px;" class="checkbox-inline" for="inlineCheckbox17">Converters</label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

In the above code checkbox coming the middle and clicking on drop down it should expand and by default it should not expand. Can someone help me to make this work as expected? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What should happen when clicking any checkbox ?

Comment: No. Dropdown options are open by default. It should open clicking on dropodwnbox list.

Comment: Right now when clicking checkbox , the list hides, it should be open ,is that you want /

Comment: not clicking on checkbox. Clicking on button it all li's should open.

Comment: Ca someone help me to make this work?

Comment: see my updated  answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I believe you want to do is add a javascript onclick function that adds and removes your checkbox when filter is clicked like so

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn-group');
let ul = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');

btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if(ul.style.display === 'none'){
        ul.style.display = 'block';  
  }else{ul.style.display = 'none'}
});
```

and here is the updated css

```
.checkbox {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .dropdown-menu {
          display:none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1000;
            float: left;
            min-width: 150px;
            max-height: 600px;
            overflow-x: visible;
            overflow-y: visible;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 500;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            border-radius: 0;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
            box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
            -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
            background-clip: padding-box;
            color: #464646;
        }

        .btn-group, .btn-group-vertical {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
toggle.btn-default {
    background: #dedede;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    border: 1px solid #2E92FA;
    color: #464646;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting below error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the `open` class first.

```js
$('.btn-group').click(function(e) { $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open'); });
```

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}
.checkbox {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
 float: left;
 min-width: 150px;
 max-height: 600px;
 overflow-x: visible;
 overflow-y: visible;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: 500;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 border-radius: 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
 box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
 -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
 background-clip: padding-box;
 color: #464646;
 transition:all .3s;
 transform: translate(-100%);
}
.dropdown-menu.open {
 transform: translate(0%);
}
.btn-group, .btn-group-vertical {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
toggle.btn-default {
    background: #dedede;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    border: 1px solid #2E92FA;
    color: #464646;
    outline: none;
}
label.checkbox-inline {
    display: contents;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Filter by<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width:100%;">
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="option1">
                <label style="margin-left:-30px; margin-right:30px;" class="checkbox-inline" for="inlineCheckbox17">Sensors</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="inlineCheckbox18" value="option1">
                <label style="margin-left:-30px; margin-right:30px;" class="checkbox-inline" for="inlineCheckbox18">Actuators</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="inlineCheckbox19" value="option1">
                <label style="margin-left:-30px; margin-right:30px;" class="checkbox-inline" for="inlineCheckbox19">Digital inputs</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox20" value="option1">
                <label style="margin-left:-30px; margin-right:30px;" class="checkbox-inline" for="inlineCheckbox20">Outputs</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox21" value="option1">
                <label style="margin-left:-30px; margin-right:30px;" class="checkbox-inline" for="inlineCheckbox21">Converters</label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not supposed to use bootstrap here.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: `$('.btn-group').click(function(e) {
       $(this).toggleClass('open); 
    });`

Answer (score 0):

remove open class from `<div class="btn-group open">` and add it when click on filter button

Answer (score 0):

[demo][1]   Here You can find a code in the demo

```
 [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/x2z08o3r/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following

**CCS**

```
.checkbox {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .dropdown-menu {
            position: relative;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1000;
            float: left;
            min-width: 250px;
            max-height: 600px;
            overflow-x: visible;
            overflow-y: visible;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 500;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            border-radius: 0;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
            box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
            -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
            background-clip: padding-box;
            color: #464646;
        }

 .dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group open">
        <button type="button" class="dropbtn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Filter by<span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="width:100%;">
            <li>
                <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                    <label style="margin-left:-15px; margin-right:15px;" class="checkbox-inline pull-right" for="inlineCheckbox17">Sensors</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="option1">

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                    <label style="margin-left:-15px; margin-right:15px;" class="checkbox-inline pull-right" for="inlineCheckbox17">Actuators</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="option1">

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                    <label style="margin-left:-15px; margin-right:15px;" class="checkbox-inline pull-right" for="inlineCheckbox17">Digital inputs</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="option1">

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                    <label style="margin-left:-15px; margin-right:15px;" class="checkbox-inline pull-right" for="inlineCheckbox17">Outputs</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="option1">

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:25px">
                    <label style="margin-left:-15px; margin-right:15px;" class="checkbox-inline pull-right " for="inlineCheckbox17">Converters</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox17" value="option1">

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```